# Scrollable XML View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I can't get a view area to scroll. I have tried many variations of tags but without success. I need the light yellow (#FFFF99) area to be very large and that the user can move it around within the view area but the buttons remain visible. Here is my XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>--><!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"--><!--android:layout_width="match_parent"--><!--android:layout_height="match_parent"--><!--android:orientation="vertical">-->
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FFCCCCCC"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:context=".MainActivity">

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/play_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:contentDescription="@string/dice6"
      android:src="@drawable/play" />

    <ImageButton
      android:id="@+id/exit_btn"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:contentDescription="@string/exit"
      android:src="@drawable/exit" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Commentary"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    adroid:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">

      <view
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        class="com.summit.DrawView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.01"
        android:background="#FFFF99"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you define "without success"? e.g. with a picture of what you want vs. what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Its because inside your scrollview the width of linear layout is wrap content. And the views width is match parent. These two contradict each other.